# Furnace burners shut off an hour after running?

Tags: hvac

Older furance that wasnt holding pressure.  Leak was found and gas valve replaced.  Gas is on.  Fired it up yesterday for the 1st time.  The house has been vacant awhile.  We had no problem.  Came back today and fired it up and ran for 1 hour.  Vents and temp were great.  Then we recognized a clicking at one point...but didnt know what it was.  About 5 minutes later I walked past a vent and realized we were back to no heat.  And the clicking noise was now obviously the burners switching off.  I can look at the flame sensor and when I get back....but it wasnt like the cycle shut down.  It was just that the burners shut off after about an hour of running.

The furance is an older Carrier Weathermaker 40k BTU  Hi Efficidncy.
At this time there arent resources to replace it for this family, but down the line, the house could use a new system.

Comment: solid state igniter or standing pilot?

Comment: Spark igniters make a clicking sound.

Answer (score 1):

Turn the power off and back on and it should work again temporarily.

Check your air filter to make sure it isn't clogged.

Get a multimeter and check the continuity of the high limit switch when working and right after it shuts off to see if that's the cause.

If it's a high combustion chamber temperature problem, then you don't have enough airflow across it. If air filter isn't clogged, then your AC evaporator coil is probably dirty.